# make new file with current time as name every 15 seconds and put into directory

Tags: shell

Create a shell script called now.bash that runs for one minute. Every 15 seconds, the shell script should create a file in a subdirectory called now that has a name of the current time in the form of YYYY-MM-DD_HH.MM.SS.now. This file should contain the statement 'It is now YYYY-MM-DD_HH.MM.SS' inside the file.

This is a problem statement that I was assigned

This is my code so far

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$SECONDS
END=$((SECONDS+60))

while [ $SECONDS -lt $END ]
do
CTIMEE=$(date +"%r")
sleep 15
echo "It is now $CTIMEE" # > /now/${CTIMEE}.now
done
```

My issue is that I get an ambiguous error, I'm thinking that I have to recursively create the files but then there is the issue of how to do that and have it to where the Date is the name of the file and it all prints into the directory

Comment: This is likely because the output of `date +%r` contains spaces, which makes your `> /now/${CTIMEE}.now` bit a little broken. Either quote the file name (i.e. `> "/now/${CTIMEE}.now"`) or use a different time format like `date +Y%m%d%H%M%D`.

Comment: Tried that and a different combination of things, I get the output of:

./now.bash: line 10: /home/students/22626/erodgers0523/lab17/now/20131120164611/20/13.now: No such file or directory

Comment: Oops... the last %D should be %S for seconds... Try `man date` to find the valid format specifiers...